# Trouble interacting with Bootstrap modals via Capybara (v2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, capybara, jquery-tokeninput, capybara-webkit

In a Rails application I'm trying to test a [Bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) with a [jQuery TokenInput field](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) in Rspec using Capybara with the `capybara-webkit` driver. The portion in question is as follows:

```
click_link 'Create Team Modal'
sleep 1

within('div#modal_popup') do
  fill_in 'input#token-input-team_name', with: 'Fancy team name'
  sleep 1
  fill_in 'input#token-input-team_name', with: '\t'
  sleep 1

  click_button 'Create Team'
end

page.should have_content('Fancy team name')
```

- Click button to get modal
- Fill in TokenInput with a team name
- Simulate a Tab key-press to get it selected
- Create the team
- Verify the name shows up on the page

This will only work with all those `sleep 1`s in place; otherwise Capybara crashes at `have_content`, eventually resulting in a server error because the team name was never able to be selected properly. Other Bootstrap modals *without* a TokenInput field do not require a `sleep 1` before they load, however.

With all that said, is there any way to get rid of the sleeps and have this proceed as normal? Capybara 2 took out `wait_until` (with good reason) since it will wait within the default wait time to test for something...but that doesn't seem to be reflected in my above test; it's as if Capybara does not engage in that wait period upon entering/exiting this modal. Anyone have any experience with this? Using Rails 3.2.10, Rspec 2.12, Capybara 2, capybara-webkit 0.14.0, TokenInput 1.6.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://blog.crowdint.com/2013/09/20/poltergeist-and-bootstrap-modals.html

Comment: See also https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/1890

Answer (score 10):

Try disabling animations in test env, layouts/application.html.erb

```
<% if Rails.env.test? %>
 <style type="text/css">
    .modal.fade, .fade {
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.01s;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.01s;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.01s;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.01s;
      transition: opacity 0.01s;
    }
 </style>
<%end%>
```

Comment: As pointed out in the [croudint article](http://blog.crowdint.com/2013/09/20/poltergeist-and-bootstrap-modals.html) that @matt linked, this can also go in a separate stylesheet.

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap is this applicable to?  I'm encountering the same issue, but I am using Bootstrap 3 and the recommendation above doesn't seem to address the issue for me.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest adding the following css into your test env:

```
  div, a, span, footer, header {
      -webkit-transition: none !important;
      -moz-transition: none !important;
      -ms-transition: none !important;
      -o-transition: none !important;
      transition: none !important;
  }

  .modal {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .modal.in {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .modal-backdrop {
    display: none !important;
  }
```

Add this js in the and of body:

```
$(".fade").removeClass("fade");
```

That has solved most of my problems with capybara and bootstrap.

Comment: It was also required (in my case) to use `gem 'capybara-webkit'`

Answer (score 2):

We just do this and it seems to work (for example to click on `$('.tp-header-login'`):

```
# instead of find(".tp-header-login")

find(".tp-header-login") # still do the find so you are sure its loaded then...
execute_script "$('.tp-header-login').click()"
```

Answer (score 1):

For those wishing to avoid `Rails.env.___?` hacks*, the following *seemed* to work (so far -- fingers crossed) in avoiding problems with testing [jQuery UI drag-and-drop functionality](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) on a Bootstrap-based modal.

First, we were already *"waiting"* for the modal to appear, using a helper method like this:

```
def wait_for_modal_to_appear
  modal = wait_until {
    # Look for the modal by ID/whatever...
  }
  raise Capybara::ModalNotFound.new('...') if modal.nil?
  return modal
end
```

Yet still, we were having spurious issues when trying to drag-and-drop elements in that modal. The following code addition, added just before the `return` line, *seems* to have done the trick:

```
page.execute_script("document.getElementById('#{modal[:id]}').classList.remove('fade');")
```

---

* Just such a hack recently led to the need for an emergency deployment at a company I work with... A bad code-change managed to make it into production because it was only activated by a `if Rails.env.production?` qualifier; it would have failed half of the test-suite otherwise.